# Load Timeline Tweets in a TableView iOS with Fabric

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, twitter, twitter-fabric

how can i show tweets from a specific user's timeline with Fabric api.
Here's my code where im trying to load tweety's ids in an array and then show them in a table view.

```
@implementation YourTweetViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[TwitterKit logInGuestWithCompletion:^(TWTRGuestSession *guestSession, NSError *error) {
    if (guestSession) {

        // Load tweets
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        NSArray *tweetIDs = @[@"20", // @jack's first Tweet
                              @"510908133917487104" // our favorite Bike tweet
                              ];

        [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]  loadTweetsWithIDs:tweetIDs completion:^(NSArray *tweets, NSError *error) {
            if (tweets) {
                typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;

                strongSelf.tweets = tweets;
                [strongSelf.tableView reloadData];

            } else {
                NSLog(@"Failed to load tweet: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unable to log in as guest: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

}

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Hi Nikos, im not getting an error. Im just want to load an entire timeline from a specific user. In that piece of code im able to show a static array of tweets reached by IDs @[@"20", @"510908133917487104"]; but i want to load a dinamic array of tweets IDs. Sorry for my english. Is my best explanation :S

Answer (score 1):

Twitter Kit 1.5.0 supports Timelines:

```
import UIKit
import TwitterKit

class ViewController: TWTRTimelineViewController {

    convenience init() {
        let client = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient
        let dataSource = TWTRUserTimelineDataSource(screenName: "fabric", APIClient: client)

        self.init(dataSource: dataSource)
    }

    override required init(dataSource: TWTRTimelineDataSource) {
        super.init(dataSource: dataSource)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to display all the tweets from a user (without knowing the tweets' ids) using TwitterKit. You have to implement your custom solution using Twitter Api v1.1 with all the limits it has.

The full reference for Twitter REST Api can be found here: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public